# How can find all files of the same extension within multiple subdirectories and move them to a seperate folder using python?

Tags: python, file-management

I have copied the contents of an older camcorder onto my computer,within the folder that was transferred there over 100 sub folders all containing 6 or 7 files I want. How am able to search through all of them and have all found files moved to a new folder?
I am rather new to this so any help is welcome.

Comment: This forum is more about helping people solve code problems rather than writing code for them. It's common to include a snippet of the code you're working on, and where you got stuck or are running into an error. If you have no idea where to start, there are many great tutorials online including the python.org documentation itself. For a quick jumpstart you should look at the `shutil` library for copying and moving files, and you can find functions to allow you to iterate over directories in the `os` library.

Comment: I can imagine it can get irritating when complete beginners in this forum are constantly asking for the simple stuff, I'll keep what you said in mind next time and thank you for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dswdsyd has the right answer here, although you could change the printout to actually move the files like so:

```
import os

path = 'C:\\location_to_root_folder\\'
newpath = 'C:\\NewPath\\'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.mpg' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    os.rename(f, newpath + f.split('/')[-1])
    print(f'{f.split('/')[-1]} moved to {newpath}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this it's so helpful, as said before on Aarons comment I understand that I should be getting whole code written for me but I can use this code to learn about all the different elements functioning with it so again cheers

Comment: I'm glad this helps, I've only been using Python for a little while myself so I understand that you'll need a lot of help to begin with. You should check out some free courses in Python.

Comment: @MichaelHerbert no worries. If an answer helped you solve your problem, you should consider marking it correct to feed our egos, and the gamification of talking to strangers online ;P

Answer (score 1):

To locate all files, there are 2 approaches:

1. Use os.walker

Example:

```
import os

path = 'c:\\location_to_root_folder\\'

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.mpg' in file:
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

for f in files:
    print(f)
```

2. Use glob
   Example:

```
import glob

path = 'c:\\location_to_root_folder\\'

files = [f for f in glob.glob(path + "**/*.mpg", recursive=True)]

for f in files:
    print(f)
```

To move, you can use either of the 3 below approaches, personally i prefer shutil.move:

```
import os
import shutil

os.rename("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
shutil.move("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
os.replace("path/to/current/file.foo", "path/to/new/destination/for/file.foo")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you input at my level all and any help is greatly appreciated